# What is the purpose of the sum(rlist) == len(list) in this code?

Tags: python, regex

The problem is Write a function matchAll(pattern, list), return True if the pattern matches all the strings in the list.

The answer is:

```
import re
def matchAll(pattern,lst):
    outlist=[(re.search(pattern, i) != None) for i in lst]
    #out = True
    #for i in outlist:
    #    out= i and out
    return sum(outlist)==len(outlist)
```

I understand everything they did except for the last line. Why do you have to check if the sum of the list is equal to the length of the list? Thanks

Comment: this is a crappy way of writting `return all(outlist)`

Answer (score 4):

`outlist` is a list of booleans. If *all* the items were `True`, the sum of all the items (`True`s are coerced as 1 and `False`s as 0) will be same as the length of the list.

The same as doing:

```
return all(outlist)
```

Answer (score 4):

`sum()` on a list of booleans counts how many of the booleans are true. Thus, the equality is checking whether every single boolean in the list is true.

```
>>> sum([True, True, True])
3
>>> len([True, True, True])
3
>>> sum([True, False, True])
2
>>> len([True, False, True])
3
```

Why? Because `sum()` converts each boolean to an integer (True is 1, False is 0) that it encounters in a list. More fun with this:

```
>>> True + True
2
>>> sum([True, 2])
3
>>> sum([0, False, 1.5])
1.5
```

`any()` is the usual way to do this, since it'll short-circuit whenever it reaches the first value in a list that's true:

```
>>> any([True, True])
True
>>> any([True, False])
True
```

Answer (score 4):

it would be much better to do

```
def matchAll(pattern, lst):
    return all(re.search(pattern, i) is not None for i in lst)
```

as this will short circuit as soon as it finds one false (rather than having to evaluate the whole list, and then even worse sum up all the trues and falses)